# HTML 5 Geolocation watchPosition

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I am trying to set up my code to locate the most accurate position on a android phone or tablet. Since getCurrentPosition doesn't give enough time for the GPS to find a location, I am using the watchPosition. This works great but I need to allow the user to stop this watchPostion so I'm using the clearWatch function. This clearWatch function works on my android phone 2.2.2 version but not on the android tablet 3.2.1 version. My other issue is on my android phone, once I stop/clearwatch and I try locating my position again my phone vibrates and the browser closes. What is the issue here? I've tried this on other phones as well and have the same problem. If anyone has any suggestions I would greatly appreciate it. Below is the code I'm using.

```
//function to locate using GPS
function ShowMyLocation(){
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    ShowProgressIndicator('map');
    watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position){
      var mapPoint = esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(new esri.geometry.Point(position.coords.longitude, position.coords.latitude, new esri.SpatialReference({
        wkid: 4326
      })));
      var graphicCollection = esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(new esri.geometry.Multipoint(new esri.SpatialReference({
        wkid: 4326
      })));
      graphicCollection.addPoint(mapPoint);
      geometryService.project([graphicCollection], map.spatialReference, function(newPointCollection){
        HideProgressIndicator();
        if (!map.getLayer(baseMapLayerCollection[0].Key).fullExtent.contains(mapPoint)) {
          alert('Data not available for the specified address.');
          return;
        }
        mapPoint = newPointCollection[0].getPoint(0);
        AddServiceRequest(mapPoint);
      });
    }, function(error){
      HideProgressIndicator();
      switch (error.code) {
        case error.TIMEOUT:
                alert('Timeout');
                break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
          alert('Position unavailable');
          break;
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
          alert('Permission denied');
          break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
          alert('Unknown error');
          break;
      }
    }, {
      timeout: 5000,
      maximumAge: 90000,
      enableHighAccuracy: true      
    });

  }
}
 function clearWatch(){
   // Cancel the updates when the user clicks a button.
  if (watchID > 0) {
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch();
    alert("Stop tracking location");
  }
}
```

Comment: why you don't set some big timeout when doing getCurrentPosition?

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is incorrect. `clearWatch` takes an argument of which watch ID to cancel.

In your case, you should have `clearWatch(watchID)`, not `clearWatch()`.